# Ver conteúdo da fila do ServiceBus da Azure

Tags: microsoft-azure

Eu gostaria de ver as mensagens (e seu conteúdo) que estão em uma das filas do ServiceBus.
Pelo [site da azure](https://manage.windowsazure.com/) eu consigo ver todas as filas do ServiceBus, quantos itens cada uma tem, seu tamanho (em bytes) e até alguns gráficos da atividade na fila ao longo do tempo, mas não achei se tem como ver cada item da fila.

Existe uma [pergunta igual a esta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10043219/view-content-of-an-azure-service-bus-queue), mas a última resposta é de 2013, então eu espero que tenha alguma novidade desde então.

Answer (score 0):

Via programação:

```
this.receiveClient = QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString, queueName, ReceiveMode.PeekLock);

receiveClient.OnMessageAsync(
        async message =>
        {
            ... the handling code is explained below ...
        },
        new OnMessageOptions {AutoComplete = false, MaxConcurrentCalls = 1});
```

mais exemplos: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-servicebus-messaging-samples

Sem programar:
https://github.com/paolosalvatori/ServiceBusExplorer